# Should I initialize a struct's variables within the constructor of its containing class?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I have a header file with a class called 'list' and a struct called 'node' within the private part of that class. Together, this class and struct will make up a doubly threaded linked list of winery objects (winery being it's own class). What I'm wondering is if it would be best to implement and de-implement the node struct's variables within the list constructor and deconstructor
(like this example, which throws errors in the compiler):

```
list::list()
{
    struct node
    {
        item = winery::winery()
        nextByName = nullptr;
        nextByRating = nullptr;
    };
    headByName = nullptr;
    headByRating = nullptr;
}
list::~list()
{
    struct node
    {
        delete item;
        delete nextByName;
        delete nextByRating;
    };
    delete headByName;
    delete headByRating;
}
```

My compiler throws an error when I delete those nodes within the list constructor and deconstructor; so the example above is obviously incorrect in some ways. But it still seems to me that a solution to this could work without this methodology, just not with this exact code.

I'm also curious if it would be better to implement and de-implement the struct separately
(like this):

```
list::node::node()
{
    item = winery::winery()
    nextByName = nullptr;
    nextByRating = nullptr;
}
list::node::~node()
{
    delete item;
    delete nextByName;
    delete nextByRating;
}
```

When I delete those elements separately (above), my constructor only throws the error for the `delete item;`. Do you know why this is? Can you explain why I don't need to delete the winery item? Should I call the winery deconstructor there?

Should I do something entirely different? I've looked online, and in my textbooks, but there really is no clear answer on this. I would really appreciate your guys help, and if you could explain why your solution is the best (if it is the best), I would be extremely grateful. I just started learning C++ a few months ago after all.

By the way, this is what my list.h file looks like:

```
#include "winery.h"

class list
{
public:
    list();
    ~list();
    void addWinery();
    void removeWinery();
    void displayByRating() const;
    void displayByName() const;
    void searchByName() const;
private:
    struct node
    {
        winery item;
        node * nextByName;
        node * nextByRating;
    }; 
    node * headByName;
    node * headByRating;
};
```

Comment: Putting `struct node {` inside a function declares a class called `node` local to that function. It seems as if you think it references a different struct node, or something.

Comment: red alert, rule of zero/three/five violation; consider copies/moves/assignments please

Answer (score 0):

To initialize, you could do this:

```
class list
{
public:
    list();
    // etc.
private:
    struct node
    {
        winery item;
        node * nextByName = nullptr;
        node * nextByRating = nullptr;
    }; 
    node * headByName = nullptr;
    node * headByRating = nullptr;
};
```

And then you do not need the constructor to take any further action.

Your destructor is suspicious though.  If each `node *` is supposed to own the object it is pointing to, then use `std::unique_ptr<node>` instead of `node *`. And if it isn't then `delete` is not the right solution.

Comment: Someone posted this comment to my question, I guess they deleted it, though: "You need to understand what `new` and `delete` actually do before writing any code. First rule is never to `delete` something that hasn't been created by `new`. The long list of errors that any compiler will give you about the above code should warn you as well." Do you know what they meant by this?

Comment: @Larrimus Yes, you seem to be just writing `delete` in your destructor without understanding what you're doing or why

Comment: As I'm aware, delete is for pointers. In that case, what should I do with the winery item? Should I call the winery destructor there? If I have an `int myint` in a class, is calling `delete &myint` practical or appropriate?

Comment: No , it is wrong. Stop doing things if you don't understand what they do. `delete` is only used for freeing objects that were allocated by `new`. You do not need to do anything for the winery item.